# Combining Yii2 controllers with Yii1 controllers

Tags: yii, controller, yii2, migration

I have a rather large Yii1 application that I want to migrate slowly to Yii2. I would like to do this gradually.

I have followed the instructions in the [Yii2 and Yii1 integration manual](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html#using-both-yii2-yii1).

And my application is running fine.

I have also tried the [yii2-yii-bridge](https://github.com/yiiext/yii2-yii-bridge) trick and it also seems to work after some tweaks.

My question is, now that I know I have both versions of Yii in my application, how can I start adding Yii2 style controllers?

If I create a simple Yii2 style controller, like this:

```php
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;


class SecondController extends Controller {

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['index'],
                'rules' => [
                    // allow authenticated users
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                    // everything else is denied
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        Yii::trace("(!!!) SecondController::index called!!!");
        return "SecondController::index!!";
    }

} // class
```

I can't access it using the URL scheme that I am used to, so http://local.url/second/index doesn't seem to be found.

However if I create a Yii1 style the way I have always done, it resolves just fine:

```php
class ThirdController extends Controller {

    public function accessRules() {
        return array(
            array('allow',
                'actions' => array('index'),
                'users' => array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }


    public function actionIndex() {
        Yii::trace("ThirdController::index called!!!");
        return "ThirdController::index!!";
    }

}
```

Seems that the default url mapping of `<controller>/<action>` cannot deal with namespaced controllers is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

> Seems that the default url mapping of / cannot deal with namespaced controllers is there a way around this?

To support namespaced controllers you need to use [`CWebModule::$controllerNamespace`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebModule#controllerNamespace-detail) for module controllers or [`CWebApplication::$controllerNamespace`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication#controllerNamespace-detail) for global application controllers. Then all controllers in given scope needs to be namespaced. If you want to use namepsaces only in some controllers, you need to use [`CWebApplication::$controllerMap`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication#controllerMap-detail) or [`CWebModule::$controllerMap`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebModule#controllerMap-detail) and configure controllers classes for specified routes.

However running Yii 2.0 controller in Yii 1.1 application most likely will not work at all. If you want to move only some part of application to Yii 2, I suggest to configure and run it as a separate application and route to proper application using rewrite rules. For example, if you move `user` module to Yii 2 you may use this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Yii 2 rules
RewriteRule ^user index-yii2.php [L]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

In `index.php` file you should have bootstrapped your application in Yii 1.1, and in `index-yii2.php` you have Yii 2 application.

Answer (score 0):

The main goal of integration is to using some of the features only available in Yii 2. Imagine that you still have a running Yii 1 application. But you add some external library with new features.

To be able using controllers from Yii 2 you should make a deep integration with Yii 1 core.

I can only suggest splitting requests to applications index files, e.g. in .htaccess and create some new functionality in Yii 2.